# No entiendo porque me da este error al usar el delete en c++

Tags: c++

No entiendo al llamar, en `main()`, a la función `DestruirParticion(particion)` lo que hace es ingresar a ese bucle donde se elimina un puntero a puntero (vector de punteros) (o sea, un vector que contiene distintos registros guardados en este caso).

El problema en esa función surge cuando pongo el bucle for donde elimino uno por uno cada registro dentro del vector de punteros, hasta donde vi nunca llega al ultimo indice del vector (tiene un tamaño de 10, pero solo llega al indice 8 del vector si se imprime los valores que toma i)

Si saco esa linea `delete particion->registros[i]` si imprime bien los indices pero no funciona correctamente debido a la linea `delete[] particion->registros[i]`.

Si solo en la función dejo delete partición funciona pero claro, debo eliminar cada registro ocupando un espacio en cada indice de este vector de punteros

Comparto la función redimensionar porque algo lei por ahi que si llamaba al `delete[]` y luego en otra funcion lo volvia a hacer, es como que c++ no sabe cuántas veces lo llamo y da error en ello. Lo dejo por si preguntan si llamo al `delete[]` en otro lugar.

Por cierto, una duda más, en redimensionar, seria correcto usar delete nuevosRegistros?, o sea, borrar el nuevo conjunto de vectores que tengo con un delete `nuevosRegistros[i]` seguido de un `delete[] nuevosRegistros;` luego de haber hecho todo redimensionamiento, antes del return. Porque tambien me da error eso

```cpp
int main() {
    Particion *particion = CrearParticion(0,10);
    AgregarRegistro(particion, "A");
    AgregarRegistro(particion, "B");
    AgregarRegistro(particion, "C");
    AgregarRegistro(particion, "D");
    AgregarRegistro(particion, "E");    
    AgregarRegistro(particion, "F");
    AgregarRegistro(particion, "G");
    AgregarRegistro(particion, "H");
    AgregarRegistro(particion, "I");
    AgregarRegistro(particion, "J");
    for(int i = 0; i < particion->cantidadRegistros; i++) {
        cout << "Nombre: " << ObtenerValor(particion->registros[i]) << endl;
        cout << "Identificador: " << ObtenerIdentificador(particion->registros[i]) << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    DestruirParticion(particion);
    return 1;
}
   
Registro **Redimensionar(Particion *particion) {
    particion->capacidadActual += 2;
    Registro **nuevosRegistros = new Registro*[particion->capacidadActual];
    if(particion->capacidadActual < particion->maximoRegistros) {
        for(int i = 0; i < particion->capacidadActual; i++)
            nuevosRegistros[i] = particion->registros[i];
         delete[] particion->registros;
    }
    else return particion->registros;
    return nuevosRegistros;
}


void DestruirParticion(Particion *particion) {
    if(particion->cantidadRegistros > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < particion->capacidadActual; i++) {
            cout << "Cantidad: " << i << endl;
            delete particion->registros[i];
        }
        delete[] particion->registros;
        delete particion;
    }
}
```

Comment: Me parece raro que uses un puntero doble. ¿Seguro que eso es lo que quieres?

Comment: ```struct Particion
{
    Registro **registros;
    int cantidadRegistros;
    int inicioRango;
    int finRango;
    int maximoRegistros;
    int capacidadActual;
};```
Sisi, para este proyecto se solicito usar una struct donde se contiene un doble puntero, como ves la estructura contiene un Registros **registros; con un tamaño que cambio a medida que agrego registros ~~editado: para redimensionar , me vino perfecto en este caso un doble puntero en esa funcion asi me devuelve un vector a punteros con los valores y espacios que necesito

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir la información que te vayan pidiendo. Los comentarios no sirven para poner código porque es ilegible. Por otro lado, te sugiero añadir la declaración de la clase `Particion`. Para hacernos una idea acerca de cómo debería usarse ese tipo de objetos

Comment: Ya esta resuelto, el problema era el programa Dev c++, no se porque da error cuando ejecutas un bucle con delete vector[i]. Gracias de todas formas